# what is the ducking ability?

Tags: 2d, game-design, physics

In my game framework I have this property:

```
canDuck : Boolean = true
Determines whether or not the hero's ducking ability is enabled.
```

What does it mean ?

regards

Comment: You should consult the documentation for whatever game framework you are using. Or at least tell us which framework it is.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about English vocabulary.

Answer (score 8):

Ducking ability could be:

- Ability to turn into a duck, for a disguise or for duck related beak attacks.
- Ability to swim like a duck, enabling escape across water.
- Ability to quack like a duck, stunning the hero's enemies.
- Ability to lay eggs like a duck, perhaps with treasure inside.
- Ability to talk to ducks for duck related conversation, or command them to defend the hero.
- Ability to crouch or duck down (not related to ducks), to get under low things or steady aim.

But seriously it's likely the last one. To be sure you can search for references to `canDuck` and see how it's used in your framework.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Crouching, ducking -- the ability for the character to go from a standing position to a hunched-up position.